# Send data to Google Analytics using Code by Zapier (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, zapier

I need to track a form fill on an external site as a custom event in Google Analytics using Code by Zapier.

Normally, the javascript you would place on your site for this would look like...

---

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', {
  trackingId: 'UA-64856741-1',
  cookieDomain: 'auto',
  name: ‘CalendlyDemoTracking’,
});

ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Videos',
  eventAction: 'play',
  eventLabel: 'Fall Campaign'
});
```

---

... Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this using [Code by Zapier](https://zapier.com/help/code/)?

Answer (score 0):

For all intents and purposes, GA is a black box. The top code loads a js file found at https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js and the bottom sections create the tracking event. It's not really meant to be hacked though, and Code only supports a vanilla node.js environment, so you won't be able to easily load the GA functions in.

If you can track the even other ways besides GA, you'll have better luck. Can you talk a bit more about what external form software you're using?

A. If you control the form, then you can fire a [webhook](https://zapier.com/zapbook/webhook/) to Zapier and track your event that way.
B. If you don't control the form, I would try and pick up whatever the result is (eg: new contact created in whatever the destination system is), since that's more likely something Zapier integrates with.